# Best Practices -- Use switchMap instead of multiple Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my project to learn Angular. I ran a function that returns multiple values using RxJS.

The problem is that I found that using several subscribers it comes down to Subscribe hell ...

I tried with SwitchMap, it worked for the first returned value, but I have to use that last returned value to return other values. the problem is that it returns me undefined value. I think I misused switchMap ...

> (I will put the 2 versions of my function) :

**Working method but with multiple Subscribe :**

```
addToCart2() {
    const { quantity } = this.productForm.value;
    const sessionCart = sessionStorage.getItem('cart_Session');

    // Get Cart ID from SessionStorage
    this.cartService
      .retrieveCart(sessionCart!)
      .subscribe(({ id: cart_ID }: Cart) => {
        console.log('ID Cart : ', cart_ID);
        console.log('Cart Already init');

        // Add to cart method
        this.cartService
          .addToCart(cart_ID, this.product_ID, quantity, this.variant_Data)
          .subscribe(
            () => {
              // Get current cart items to send Total items to Header
              this.cartService.retrieveCart(cart_ID).subscribe((items) => {
                this.cart_Items = items.line_items;
                this.total_Items = items.total_unique_items;
                this.cartService._totalItems$.next(this.total_Items);
              });
              // Modal Success TODO !!
            },

            (err) => {
              console.log('Error in Request !!!', err);
            },

            () => {
              console.log('Add to Cart Finish.');
            }
          );
      });
  }
```

Using SwitchMap but not working completely :

```
addToCart__NotWorking() {
// Test
const { quantity } = this.productForm.value;
const sessionCart = sessionStorage.getItem('cart_Session');

this.cartService
  .retrieveCart(sessionCart!)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(({ id: cart_ID }) => {
      console.log('SwitchMap', cart_ID);
      return this.cartService.addToCart(
        cart_ID,
        this.product_ID,
        quantity,
        this.variant_Data
      );
    }),
    switchMap(({ id: cart_ID }) => {
      return this.cartService.retrieveCart(cart_ID);
    })
  )
  .subscribe((values) => {
    console.log('SwitchMap Final True : ', values);
  });
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you seem to be loosing the cart_id between the switchMaps, `return this.cartService.addToCart` does not return the id, at least according to your nested subscribes, you instead there use the same cart id which you pass to `addToCart`. What you can do, is to use `mapTo` as you don't seem to need the response returned by `this.cartService.addToCart`. So, you could do:

```
switchMap(({ id: cart_ID }) => {
  console.log('SwitchMap', cart_ID);
  return this.cartService.addToCart(
    cart_ID,
    this.product_ID,
    quantity,
    this.variant_Data
  ).pipe(
     mapTo({ id: cart_ID }) // here, now it returns the id!
   );
}),
// .....
```